# How do I get a particular value in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How do I prase this?

```
$scope = $facebook->api('/me/permissions','GET');
```

The result is as follows and I want to get the value of *installed*:

```
array(1) { ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["installed"]=> int(1) ["offline_access"]=> int(1) ["email"]=> int(1) ["manage_pages"]=> int(1) ["user_about_me"]=> int(1) } } }
```

I've tried `json_decode($scope, true)`, `$scope['installed']`, `$scope['data']['installed']` etc. What am I missing?

Comment: Is that result an ```echo``` of the $scope variable?

Comment: no its var_dump($scope)... the answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a super nested array - Your $scope['data']['installed'] was close. However, you forgot one layer. It should be $scope['data'][0]['installed']. Note the 0 in there - there is a third level.

Accessing any of the scope will start with $scope['data'][0], so I would assign that to a new var to remove those two layers.

```
$scope = $scope['data'][0]
```

Then, all you need is the key for the permission

Answer (score 1):

Try `$scope['data'][0]['installed']`